# How to access nested keys and their values to modify or delete all at once?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

Learning python and stuff due to my need of collecting bunch of data for my project and I am stuck here. I am using scrapy to scrape a json response from an API which looks like this;

```
  "status": "ok",
  "status_message": "Query was successful",
  "data": {
    "product_count": 40993,
    "limit": 20,
    "page_number": 1,
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 41789,
        "url": "https://anything1.com",
        "product_name": "product1",
        "manufacturing_date": "19.12.2014",
        "rating": 5.3,
        "material": "something",
        "description": "",
        "cover_image": "anycover1.com",
        "state": "ok",
        "variants": [
          {
            "url": "https://anyvariant1.com",
            "product_code": "55BEF7",
            "material": "something",
            "size": "small",
            "dimensions": ""          },
          {
            "url": "https://anyvariant2.com",
            "product_code": "55BEF8",
            "material": "something",
            "size": "medium",
            "dimensions": ""          },
          {
            "url": "https://anyvariant3.com",
            "product_code": "55BEF9",
            "material": "something",
            "size": "large",
            "dimensions": ""          }          
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 41790,
        "url": "https://anything2.com",
        "product_name": "product2",
        "manufacturing_date": "02.10.2014",
        "rating": 7.2,
        "material": "something",
        "description": "",
        "cover_image": "anycover2.com",
        "state": "ok",
        "variants": [
          {
            "url": "https://anyvariant4.com",
            "product_code": "55BEG7",
            "material": "something",
            "size": "small",
            "dimensions": ""          },
          {
            "url": "https://anyvariant5.com",
            "product_code": "55BEG8",
            "material": "something",
            "size": "medium",
            "dimensions": ""          },
          {
            "url": "https://anyvariant6.com",
            "product_code": "55BEG9",
            "material": "something",
            "size": "large",
            "dimensions": ""          }          
        ]
      },
      {
        _______
      },
      {
        _______
      }      
    ]
  },
  "@meta": {
    "server_time": 1651288705,
    "execution_time": "0.01 ms"
  }
}
```

And this is how my scraper code looks like;

```
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    data_main = data['data']['products']
    product_list = []
    for item in data_main:
        id = item['id']
        url = item['url']
        product_name = item['product_name']
        rating = item['rating']
        cover_image = item['cover_image']
        description = item['description']
        product = {
            'id': id,
            'url': url,
            'name': product_name,
            'image': cover_image,
            'rating': rating,
            'description': description
        }
        product_list.append(product)
    return product_list
```

With this keys and values of id, url, name, image, rating, description are accessible. But unable to access and modify the nested keys and their values all at once (and ignore some keys and values). So how can I do that? And if there is any other better code to achieve what I need then please suggest.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By nested keys and values, I assume you mean the ones under `variants`.  You can access those in much the same way as you iterated through items:

```py
variant_list = []
for variant in item[variants]:
    url = variant['url']
    # and so on... for whatever other keys you're interested in
    new_variant = {'url':url} # and whatever other keys you want
    variant_list.append(new_variant)
```

I have to wonder, though, why you're reconstructing dictionaries that are similar to ones that JSON gave you?  For many purposes, you might as well stick with the dictionary that JSON gave you.

Comment: To remove and modify certain keys and their values. Is there any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you already have the relevant info in lists and dictionaries, so e.g., the list you eventually create called `product_list` is quite similar to the list that you already had called `data_main`, with the main difference being that you didn't copy quite all of the contained features.  For most purposes, you could just use `data_main` directly for whatever you were thinking of using `product_list` for.

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably want to work with custom Python objects, rather than just dictionaries, so e.g. I could refer to `product.url` rather than `product['url']`.  To do that, you'd want to create a class, e.g. with `class Product: pass`, and then you can make a new `Product` object with `product = Product()`.  When you have a JSON-style dictionary called `item` that maps attribute names to values, an easy way to copy those to be attributes of the object `product` would be `product.__dict__.update(item)`.  After this, you can refer to that product's url as `product.url`.

Comment: To remove a value from dictionary `d`, you can use `d.pop(key)` (where in your case `key` would be something like `'url'`).  To modify a value in a dictionary, you can use `d[key] = value`.  If you convert dictionaries to objects as I suggested above, to remove an attribute `.url` from object `p`, use `del p.url`, or to modify that attribute, use `p.url = new_value`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have been using custom python objects approach and it's far more easier than using dictionaries.